How can I avoid using all plant positions as decision variables when using MinimumDistanceLowerBoundConstraint?
I want to solve a non-penetration projection NLP. I have a plant with a bunch of floating bodies and I want to only selectively optimize certain parts of the object positions (e.g. translation only or only the z-component of the translation).
To simplify things, I would like to use MinimumDistanceLowerBoundConstraint. However, it doesn't seem to be possible to use it with fewer decision variables than the number of positions in the plant.
What options do I have for only declaring decision variables for a subset of my plant positions?
I would prefer not to modify my existing plant by adding joints if it can be avoided.
I have a version where I add additional constraints for constraining the parts that I don't want to optimize to stay the same. However, I don't end up finding a feasible solution and hope that the problem will be easier to solve with fewer decision variables. Maybe I shouldn't expect this?

adding linear equality constraints to fix the variables that you don't want to move is the solution I would have suggested. For some of the commercial solvers, I would expect that they have preprocessing that makes this almost as good as removing the variables. For the nonlinear solvers like SNOPT, I would still expect that it doesn't make the problem much harder.

Okay, thanks! Looks like I just expected too much from these solvers then.
